# "write() argument must be str, not bytes"

Tags: python, password-generator

I am making a password generator in Python 3.9, and I get the syntax error in the title, my code is as follows.(Also, I don't know if my syntax works with python 3.9 as the article I'm reading made this in python 2.7)

```
from passwordmeter import test
from urllib.request import urlopen
from os.path import isfile 
from random import choice,randint

if not isfile('words.txt'):
    print ('Downloading words.txt ...')
    url='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words.txt'
    with open('words.txt','w') as f:
        f.write(urlopen(url).read())

words=open('words.txt', 'r').read().split("\n")
special_chars=['!','?']

def create_password(num_words=2, num_numbers=4, num_special=1):
    pass_str=''

    for _ in xrange(num_words):
        pass_str+-choice(words).lower().capitalize()
    for _ in xrange(num_numbers):
        pass_str+-(randint(0,9))
    for _ in xrange(num_special):
        pass_str+-(special_chars)
    return pass_str
    
def main():
    pass_str=create_password()
    strength,_=test(pass_str)

    print ('\nPassword: %s')%pass_str 
    print ('Strength: %0.5f')%strength

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `f.write(urlopen(url).read().decode())`

Comment: Or open with mode `'wb'` instead of `'w'` if you _want_ to write bytes instead of unicode codepoints.